# How to hide checkbox options when another checkbox is selected in ms-word

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word, ms-office

I'm in the process of trying to put together a form in ms-word, in which it is desired that if a user checks 1 of 3 check-box options, the other two and their adjacent text will be hidden.

I'm aware of how to hide the content some-what, but I'm completely unfamiliar with VBA/programming as a whole, so I don't quite know what is wrong in my If/Else loop, but it definitely doesn't show/hide everything.

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)

If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox1" And ContentControl.Checked = True Then
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Approve").Range.Font.Hidden = True
Else
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Approve").Range.Font.Hidden = False
End If

If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox2" And ContentControl.Checked = True Then
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Denied 1").Range.Font.Hidden = True
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Denied 2").Range.Font.Hidden = True
Else
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Sign1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Sign2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
End If

If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox3" And ContentControl.Checked = True Then
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("pending").Range.Font.Hidden = True
Else
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("pending").Range.Font.Hidden = False
End If

End Sub
```

If I only keep one of the if/else parts it does work fine, but when I keep all 3 it doesn't work.

Any guidance is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox1" And ContentControl.Checked = True Then
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Approve").Range.Font.Hidden = True
Else
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Approve").Range.Font.Hidden = False
End If
```

You set "approve" to hidden if the title is "checkbox1" *and* Checked is True, but the `Else` will run when only one (*or neither*) of those is true.  So your `Else` clauses always run in the other two blocks not connected to the clicked control.

would be better like this:

```
If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox1" Then
    If ContentControl.Checked = True Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Approve").Range.Font.Hidden = True
    Else
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Approve").Range.Font.Hidden = False
    End If
End If
```

or (shorter):

```
If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox1" Then

    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Approve").Range.Font.Hidden = _
                         (ContentControl.Checked = True)

End If
```

Whole thing:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim bChecked As Boolean
    bChecked = (ContentControl.Checked = True)

    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox1" Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Approve").Range.Font.Hidden = bChecked
    End If

    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox2" Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Denied 1").Range.Font.Hidden = bChecked
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Denied 2").Range.Font.Hidden = bChecked
    End If

    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox3" Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("pending").Range.Font.Hidden = bChecked
    End If

End Sub
```